# Production site is popping up sandbox.paypal payment window instead of just paypal.com payment window

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, paypal

I have a paypal "smart button" payment gateway on a site. The sandbox version on local testing seemed to be working perfectly fine, but once I pushed to production, the payment popup window still says sandbox.paypal.com/etc

I've made sure that my .env file on prod has the following settings:

```
APP_ENV = production

and

PAYPAL_MODE = live
```

(as well as obviously all the sandbox and prod secrets and client IDs. am I missing any ids that are needed here?)

I have this paypal.php in my config folder (i'm using Laravel):

```
<?php
/**
 * PayPal Setting & API Credentials
 */


if ( env('APP_ENV') == 'local' || env('APP_ENV') == 'staging') {
    return array(
        'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID'),
        'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET'),
        'settings' => array(
            'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'),
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 3000,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => env('PAYPAL_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        ),
    );
}

if ( env('APP_ENV') == 'production' ) {
    return array(
        'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_PROD_CLIENT_ID'),
        'secret' => env('PAYPAL_PROD_SECRET'),
        'settings' => array(
            //payment mode, 'sandbox' or 'live'
            'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'live'),
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 3000,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => env('PAYPAL_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        ),
    );
}
```

then in my controller that processes payments, I added this construct. I think that this might be where I'm doing something wrong because I'm not sure if I'm missing something here:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        /** PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $paypal_conf['client_id'],
                $paypal_conf['secret'])
        );
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }
```

I'm not sure where else this issue could be being caused but let me know and I can add the code! I'm using a laravel and vuejs stack

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Take a look at this comment [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/539#issuecomment-224927165) !

Comment: HMM interesting, I'll try it now, but won't i need to redo this every time i rebuild the site on prod and paypal updates? @Maraboc

Comment: looking now it looks like there are constants for both sandbox and live in that file, I'm pretty sure there's something wrong that I'm doing in configuration that isn't allowing the site to see that we're on live

Comment: just tried it it made no difference

Comment: It seems like you need to do some more basic debugging and printing out of values at runtime to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this!! It turned out that I was importing the friggin sandbox API's SDK in the layout of the site instead of the normal non-sandbox SDK

SIGH